# Execution time is high to read CAN message using BLFReader in python

Tags: python-3.x, can-bus

I am reading CAN message from BLF file using BLFReader in python.
But statement "list(log)" is taking more than 1 minute to execute.

```
import can

log = can.BLFReader(selectedTraceFile)
log = list(log)
for msg in log:
    print(msg)
```

How to improve the this execution time or is there any way to read CAN data?

Comment: You should be able to iterate over your messages without converting log to list. Just delete `log = list(log)`